# LuaTeX example invalid (printing)

Tags: luatex

On page 127 of the `luatex` manual it has the example

```
before\directlua{tex.sprint("\\relax")tex.sprint(" inbetween")}after
```

but the double slash throws an error. Similarly a single slash also has the same problem.

Obviously `tex` or `luatex` is is not treating the `\\` as I expect. (I assume `tex` is trying to parse it as a macro.)

So what is the else is needed to get the sample to run?

Comment: The `luatex` manual is written in ConTeXt, and `\\ ` is unexpandable macro (or a protected macro in LaTeX's parlance). So, the above example works in ConTeXt but not in LaTeX or plain tex. Add a `\noexpand` before `\\ ` to get it to work in LaTeX.

Comment: ok, that explains a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only there fore demonstration purpose. The reference manual is written with no specific format / macro package in mind. Therefore it doesn't know if `\\` is defined or not. You can emulate a "pristine" behavior by putting the code in the *luacode** environment from the *luacode* package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
before\begin{luacode*}
tex.sprint("\\relax")tex.sprint(" inbetween")
\end{luacode*}
after
\end{document}
```

But (I keep on about it) you should rather put all Lua code in a separate file. Then you don't get into trouble.

Comment: OT, but in ConTeXt, I have not had any difficulties mixing TeX and Lua code in a single file. Can you clarify why the situation in LaTeX is different or if separating Lua and TeX code is desirable in ConTeXt as well.

Comment: @Aditya with the environment _luacode_ or _luacode*_ things are mostly harmless. I think that one of these environments (probably _luacode_) behaves like ConTeXt's environment. So the advise is not really necessary when you use this environment. But I see a lot of people trying to write code in `\directlua{...}` which breaks, because the catcodes are not changed, and thus for example a `~` expands to something that is unwanted in most cases. When you put code in a separate file, you don't need to think about it.